# Run applications in a non-admin account(when gpedit.msc is disabled by admin) in xp

Tags: windows-xp, gpedit

How can I run restricted applications in a non-admin account if gpedit.msc is disabled by an admin. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loging in with a standard user account with no administrative rights and Gpedit.msc is disabled, there is not a lot that you can do. I've been checking on the web to prove I could be wrong but...

Answer (score 4):

No, that's pretty much the point of the restricted applications functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use restricted programs without admin rights (i know this works on Windows 7+). Uniextractor/unzip probably won't work because it still can't run admin applications.

1. Place your installer that needs admin (has the UAC icon on it) on your desktop.
2. Open notepad.
3. Enter this code:

   ```
   set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker
   start "" "Name of Installer File.exe"
   ```
4. File > Save As..
5. File Type (All Files)
6. Save to desktop as IgnoreAdmin.bat
7. Open file.
8. Done :)

This basically sets the internal compatibility settings to run the file at the highest privilege you have no matter what the file's preset RunAs parameter is. Some files will still check for admin afterwards.
To get the file to install correctly, you need to select a directory of installation that doesn't require admin (Installing to C:/Program Files/AppName won't work). Try installing to the desktop/AppName.

Answer (score -1):

U can install and use restricted programs without admin rights on xp and 7.
 U have to use uniextractor to unzip and install the files. it works 100%

link:

http://www.zshare.net/download/550127 ...

Comment: Your link is broken, you might wanna fix it.

Comment: False, if an app need to be run as admin, it won't work without admin.